# Asp .NET Core 3.1 - deploying to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core

I recently wrote my first ASP .NET Core (3.1) Web App,

Now I'm looking to deploy it to IIS.

Two guides on deploying that I've read mention adding the following code block:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
  .UseKestrel()
  .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
  .UseIISIntegration()
  .UseStartup<Startup>()
  .Build();
```

However, the Program.cs in My App (as generated by MSVS) simply has:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

The Startup.cs file has a

```
public void Configure(...)
```

method, but this doesn't contain either `.UseKestrel()` OR `.UseIISIntegration()`

I've deployed my App to IIS Server (by creating an Application Pool).  I get no response at http://localhost/MyApp

I looked at the Windows Application Log, and the logs in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1, but I'm not seeing anything obvious

Any advice on how to diagnose this is appreciated

Comment: Please look at the [official documentation on hosting ASP.NET Core in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: @poke I have read that documentation, but it doesn't refer to the `.UseIISIntegration()` I see in other installation guides, i.e. https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/

Comment: does  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) call `UseIISIntegration` in the background?

Comment: Yes, the default builder takes care of IIS integration for you.

Comment: You will need to set the app pool to no managed code as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know that time has passed but still.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseKestrel();
            });
```

Do not add: `.Build();`